# How to correctly pass data between two Azure PowerShell Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, invoke-webrequest

I have two PowerShell Azure functions. The first one collects data and the second one pushes data to an Azure Storage Table. I can see my first function is calling the second function but the second function isn't getting the data. Here is my first function:

```
$body = @{"partitionKey"="01";"rowKey"="02";"userId"="00001"} 
$dataJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$functionUri = 'https://functionNumber2'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $functionUri -Method POST -Body $dataJson
```

And my second function looks like this:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$tableData = $Request.Body.Address

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

Write-Host "Name $name"

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})

Push-OutputBinding -Name tableName -Value $tableData -Clobber
```

The error I'm getting is `ERROR: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Value' because it is null. Exception : Type : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException Message : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Value' because it is null.` And if I print out `$tableData` there is nothing there. I am doing something wrong when passing the data.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Well, the first thing I see is that you are passing a dictionary which doesn't contain any key on which you are trying to select in your 2nd function. The 2nd function is looking for a key Address if i am not mistaken. Maybe you should first look at what kind of body is being sent to the default HTTP Trigger function. And then change your body, and what the function will trigger on, after knowing what the body is supposed to look like. I have never done this from PS, I have only done it from Python. So maybe this? $body = @{"Name"="GreenSaber";"Address"="PSAddress"}

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end I observed that you are receiving this error because of the below line.

```
$tableData = $Request.Body.Address
```

I could able to make this work by using the below line.

```
$tableData = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-Json
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]